# Python aiorgam передача сообщения с кнопки в машину состояния

Tags: python, aiogram

```py
async def cm_start(message: types.CallbackQuery):
    await FSMbay.text.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'какой то текст {message.data}', reply_markup=cansel_bt)


async def load_text(message: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['text'] = message.text
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN, f"{str(read)} {message.data}")
    await state.finish()
```

Подскажите как передать `{message.data}` в сообщение админу.

Answer (score 0):

По идее так, но опять же очень мало кода

```
async def load_text(message: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['text'] = message.text
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN, f"{data['text']} {message.data}")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: line 58, in load_text
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN, f"{data['text']} {message.data}")
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: нету там у message data

Comment: ну возможно стоит дополонить код чем-то еще

Comment: так у вас хендлер на сообщения, а вы ищете там callback data

Comment: в то и то и дело что мне нужно его туда передать с кнопки, а я к своему малому опыту не знаю как его передать туда, если кто знает как это передать подскажите